# How to filter a paged and sorted external list

Tags: bcs, filter, external-list

I have succesfully implented an external content type with a read list method, which can sort and page through the external data.

The external content type has 4 filters (two limit and two wildcard) which are connected with the parameters of the `ReadList` method.

```
public static IEnumerable<Entity> ReadList(int firstRow, int pageSize, string sortField, string sortDirection)
{ }
```

The view's `<Method>` element is defined as follows.

```
<Method Name="ReadList">
    <Filter Name="FirstRow" Value="{dvt_firstrow}" />
    <Filter Name="PageSize" Value="30" />
    <Filter Name="SortField" Value="{dvt_sortfield}" />
    <Filter Name="SortDirection" Value="{dvt_sortdir}" />
</Method>
```

The next step is to take account of the filter. I have observed that whenever I click the drop down button of a column the filter values are the ones which come from the first 30 items (page size). Trying to set a filter on a column calls the same `ReadList` method with `firstRow` set to 0 and `pageSize` to 30.

Is there a way to say that whenever the drop down menu for a column is pressed another instance of a read list emthod should be used? That instance could read the filter values from all the data in the external system.